# Postgres. Есть ли массив элементов в поле типа json. Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2, запрос, преобразование-типов

Есть обычная выборка (Yii 2)

```
Elements::find()->all();
```

В таблице `elements` есть поле `values` типа `integer[]`, default: `'{}'::integer[]`

Пример данных в этом поле `{257967,257968,257966,257962,257965,257963,257964,257969,257970,257960,257909}`
А у меня есть массив значений, например `[257963, 257968, 257970, 257967]`
Нужно добавить условие в запрос:

```
Elements::find()->where(???)->all();
```

Которое могло бы найти все значения записей с базы, если все 4 значения из моего примера встречаются в поле `values`

Comment: `where values @> array[257963, 257968, 257970, 257967]`. Как это объяснить вашему query builder не знаю, потому это не ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, это оно. ->where("values @> '{257963, 257968, 257970, 257967}'")